# Re open all default panes in gimp?

Tags: gimp

I installed gimp some time ago and have lost some panes. I researched how to open the [toolbox pane](https://superuser.com/questions/645532/i-accidentally-closed-my-gimp-toolbox-can-i-get-it-back), but I am not sure what else should be open.

Currently, I have two panes visible on screen, "Untitled" (the pane with a design in it), and "Layers - Brushes" (a pane with 'mode', 'opacity', 'lock', 'brushes', 'patterns', 'gradients').

Is there a shortcut to open all the panes up in Gimp, and if it cannot be done with a simple shortcut, is there a way to open them incrementally (noting that I have no idea what panes *should* be open, and I prefer to to reinstall).

Note: I found 'Toolbox' by going to Help -> search -> 'Toolbox' -> New Toolbox (it says the shortcut for this is <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>)

Comment: This technically doesn't answer the OP's question, but I expect it's much more likely that people will run into this problem by accidentally hitting TAB than accidentally (?) closing every single toolbox. Please see: https://superuser.com/a/1051177/8842

Answer (score 1):

The state of open panes is not part of the program, it is part of *your settings,* so it is not something that I'd expect a reinstallation to reset.

If you want to reset all pane positions, GIMP stores them in a file called `sessionrc`. Delete that file (while GIMP is *not* running) and your main window will return to the default layout the next time you start it.

- Linux: either `~/.config/GIMP/2.10/sessionrc`
- Windows: `%AppData%\GIMP\2.10\sessionrc`
- macOS: dunno, probably `~/Library/GIMP/2.10/sessionrc`?

(The "sessionrc" file contains just the window layout. Other settings are kept in their own files – for example, "toolrc" describes how the toolbox buttons are grouped, "gimprc" contains miscellaneous other settings. Open each file in a text editor to see what's inside.)

Comment: Thanks heaps for this. I just reinstalled but will try these suggestions. Do you know if there are bunch of recommended panes for beginners to start working with? Seems a graphic design program that doesn't have a 'fill' button by default is like a car without wheels or a library without books. It's not necessary terrible (heck, it could be a hover car!), but it sure seems unintuitive.

Comment: Hm, but GIMP _does_ have the "Bucket Fill" button in the toolbox by default?

Comment: On mac it's in `~/Library/Application Support/GIMP/2.10/sessionrc` BTW, you might find it easier to run the Mac port of Gimp. It's a whole lot more mac-like & a bit smoother running than the official build.  https://www.partha.com/

Comment: @Tetsujin great to know, thanks